# How to deal with the chunk data with jquery on foreach function on laravel blade view

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

```
 @foreach($chunks as $chunk)
       <div class="time" style="display:inline">??? </div> 
 @endforeach
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
      var timelast={{$chunk->timelast}};
      var t = timelast.split(/[- :]/);
      var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
      $('.time').text("d");
});
```

How can I get the `{{chunk->timelast}}` processed by the jquery to put in the right place(??)?

Comment: `jquery` code snippet should in `document.ready()` block, so that the `time` container is rendered and value can be set.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do it:

```
@foreach($chunks as $chunk)
       <div class="time" style="display:inline">{{$chunk->timelast}}</div>
@endforeach

(function(){
    $('.time').each(function(index, element) {
        element = $(element);
        var timelast=element.html();
          var t = timelast.split(/[- :]/);
          var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
          element.html(d);
    });
});
```

I'll be there if you need more explanation what I'm doing here.